# How do I determine which version of THREDDS Data Server I am using?

Tags: tomcat7, thredds

We are running THREDDS Data Server under Tomcat 7.0.76 and are trying to determine which version of TDS we are running. We're not seeing it in catalina.out or anywhere obvious in the config and were wondering if the version could be interrogated at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

While I'd love to know if there was a command to determine the THREDDS Data Server version, I was able to figure it out by doing a catalog listing from the browser. Our THREDDS Data Server version is 4.6.16.1